# Chrome CSS Drop Down Menu Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a navigation bar with some nodes that have a drop down menu to show more options, everything works wonderfully in IE/Firefox but in Chrome on :hover the links go transparent instead of having a nice background color like in IE and Firefox.

Here is a JSFiddle, if you run it in Chrome and hover over the `Admin` option you will see the drop down and extended options, when hovering over those they should display similar to the top level items but they do not.

http://jsfiddle.net/6jX5J/

Anyone see any problems in the HTML or CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you CSS selector from descendant to a child selector in:

```
#nav li:hover
```

Change to

```
#nav>li:hover
```

Comment: I second the request to explain why this is solving the problem, I was thoroughly confused by it not working in chrome and this being the fix.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why it doesn't work in Chrome.  Basically the position: relative; rule was being applied to both the top level li and the second level li.  For some reason Chrome was reacting strangely to the second level li positioning attribute.  Sorry I can't be of more help.